# Read elasticsearch index using Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

**I am trying to read elasticsearch index using Pyspark (v1.6.3), but getting following error**

I am using following snippet to read/load the index

```
    es_reader = sql_context.read.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
                .option("es.nodes", "x.x.x.x,y.y.y.y,z.z.z.z")
                .option("es.port", "9200").option("es.net.ssl","true")
                .option("es.net.http.auth.user", "*****")
                .option("es.net.http.auth.pass", "*****")
    sde_df = es_reader.load("index_name/doc_type")
```

**Error:**

```
22_0452/container_1547624497922_0452_02_000001/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 813, in __call__
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1547624497922_0452/container_1547624497922_0452_02_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 45, in deco
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1547624497922_0452/container_1547624497922_0452_02_000001/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 308, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o72.load.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/sources/StreamSinkProvider

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.sources.StreamSinkProvider
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 49 more
```

**Environment:**

Spark v1.6.3

Elasticsearch 5.4.3

Comment: Since your program is complaining for the org.apache.spark.sql.sources.StreamSinkProvider class missing is can that the ES driver you are using is not compatible with the Spark version or the ES jar is not present

Comment: yes got it,there was issue with compatibility
Thanks mate